# df, du report incorrect disk usage

Tags: disk-usage

`df` and `du` both incorrectly report that my root partition, a 100GB SSD, has no remaining space and uses 100G respectively; 85G in `/home/steven` alone.  A simple summing of the disk usage provided by `du`, however, reports less than 13G used.

How can I fix this?

Specifically:

```
~ » du -sh ~
85G   /home/steven

~ » du -b ~ | wc -l
15041

~ » du -h ~ | sort -h | tail -n 1
85G   /home/steven # 91088489808 bytes if using -b for du

~ » du -b ~ | sort -n | head -n 15040 | cut -f 1 | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$i=0;}$i+=$_;END{print $i.qq|\n|;}'
12735983847 # 11-12G, roughly
```

There's a huge discrepancy between 85G and 11G or 12G, obviously.  I ran `lsof +L1` and eliminated all of the processes with files marked `deleted`, but still no luck.

I have several soft links in `$HOME` pointing to directories (e.g., `repos`) on an external hard drive, which may be an issue based on some Stack Exchange posts I read, but I can't seem to understand it.

What should I do next?

Comment: What about a `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/...`?

Comment: No change in `du` after running that, unfortunately, but it did free up 5G per `df`.

Comment: Why would you filter out deleted files? They're still going to be on disk until the file handle is closed.

Comment: I'd also turn your reserved space back on unless this is on the `/home` filesystem. If it's on root you actually need that space, just probably not as much space as it reserved automatically.

Comment: @Bratchley, I ran `kill -9` on all of the PIDs. Won't that release the file handles?  Also, how much space would you recommend allocating?

Comment: What does `du -sb ~` say? It should be more accurate than summing the output of `du -b ~`, because the latter includes directory totals multiple times. (Assuming no integer overflow; haven't looked at the src code)

Comment: `du -sb ~` returns 91296460205, but the sum of `du -sb ~/*` is only 1690166532.

Comment: `~/*` is a subset of `~`.

Comment: Technically, yes, but what does `~/*` exclude other than the directory entry itself?

Comment: @StevenEdwards If you killed the PID then the files wouldn't show up in `lsof` since the program would have exited.

Comment: `~/*` doesn't include files and directories that begin with a dot. These are generally log files and configuration files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`du` does a depth-first traversal of the given tree. By default, it shows the usage of every directory tree, showing the inclusive disk usage of each:

```
$ du ~
4      /home/bob/Videos
40     /home/bob/.cache/abrt
43284  /home/bob/.cache/mozilla/firefox
43288  /home/bob/.cache/mozilla
12     /home/bob/.cache/imsettings
48340  /home/bob/.cache
4      /home/bob/Documents
48348  /home/bob
```

If given the `-a` option, it will additionally show the size of every file.

With the `-s` option, it will show just the total size of each argument file or directory tree.

```
$ du -s ~
48348  /home/bob
$ du -s ~/*
4      /home/bob/Videos
4      /home/bob/Documents
```

So, when you ran

```
$ du -b ~ | wc -l
15041

$ du -b ~ | sort -n | head -n 15040 | cut -f 1 | \
    perl -ne 'BEGIN{$i=0;$i+=$_;END{print $i.qq|\n|;}'
12735983847
```

you were summing up the size of everything under your home directory - multiple times, unfortunately, because the size reported on each line is inclusive of all subdirectories - but because you omitted the final line of du's output, which would be the line for `/home/steven`, `du` *didn't count the size of any of the regular files in the top level of your home directory*. So the sum didn't include your very large `.xsession-errors` file.

And when you ran

```
du -sb ~ returns 91296460205, but the sum of du -sb ~/* is only 1690166532
```

your `du -sb ~/*` output didn't include any files or directories in your home directory that begin with `.`.

Both `du ~ | tail -1` and `du -s ~` should do a reasonable job of showing your home directory's disk usage (not including deleted-but-open files, of course), but if you want to sum up all the file sizes without relying on `du`, you can do something like this (assuming a modern `find` that supports the `printf %s` format to show the size in bytes):

```
find ~ -type f -printf '%s\n' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$i=0;$i+=$_;END{print $i.qq|\n|;}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, Mark. And the `-printf` trick, which is much quicker than the `-exec du -h '{}' \;` that I used.

Answer (score 2):

You're summing the bytes, but the filesystem's block size is probably much larger than 1 byte. For an accurate count, you should be rounding each file's size up so that it's a multiple of the filesystem blocksize.

With GNU coreutils installed, you can run `stat --file-system $HOME` to find the block size of the filesystem.

On average, files will waste half a block. Multiply half a block by the number of files in $HOME and see if the result is close to 70GiB. If so, then your mystery is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the block size tip.  `$HOME`'s block size is 4096 bytes.  Including directories (`find ~ | wc -l`), `$HOME` has 81846 files--more than what `du` found.

Comment: .xsession-errors was 83GB, per `du -h .xsession-errors`.  Oddly, that file was excluded from `du -h ~/ | sort -h`.

Comment: After deleting that file, `du -sh /` shows 20G now, but `df` shows 97% usage.

Comment: `lsof +L1` shows that the `.xsession-errors` file descriptor is still open, held by `gdm`.  Would it be a disaster if I truncate the file in `/proc/pid/fd/`?

Comment: `sudo truncate -s 0 /proc/[pid]/fd/[fd]` worked.